# How to start playing first song in playlist after all songs are over?

Tags: itunes, macos, music, playlist

I listen to music on my Mac every day. However after a playlist ends, playback stops and I have to hit `Play` manually to start playing the playlist again from the beginning.

Is there anyway to restart a playlist automatically after it has finished playing the last song?

Answer (score 1):

Simply enable **Repeat** → `All`. Right-click **iTunes** on your Dock, and the option will appear.

[image: Repeat All]

There are several other locations, such as the menu bar item **Controls** → **Repeat** → `All`, or this icon at the top of your iTunes window, opposite the album art: [image: Repeat]

Comment: Make sure that Shuffle is not checked on if you want to play from the very first song in the playlist. Otherwise random song will be played.